# Different styles for Windows forms in Ironpython

Tags: winforms, ironpython

I want to change the look of my Ironpython windows forms, Is it possible to change the style of the form and for example make it more like a Mac?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As an interface designer, it's important to use an many standard windows controls as possible. The more your app looks like the microsoft ones users are used to, they will become more comfortable with it quicker.

A good example is how out of place iTunes and Safari look in windows. My tip is to just keep it with the windows look.

Comment: While this is good advice, this doesn't answer the question, so it would be more suitable as a comment instead. And it's not uncommon for clients or managers to insist engineers do questionable things, and in those cases, engineers come to StackOverflow too.

Answer (score 0):

See [Graphics and Drawing in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a36fascx.aspx), or [Custom Control Painting and Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf.aspx).
`WinForms` provides hooks to change the look of its controls, or you can create your own.

If possible, look into changing your app to [`WPF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441.aspx), where the separation of style and behavior is a central part of the design.

A simple example, [WPF GUI using XamlReader](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/WPF_GUI_using_XamlReader), shows how IronPython might use `WPF`.